# How to restore a Google Play adb backup to use it with another version of the app (downloaded with another app store)?

Tags: google-play-store, adb, backup, restore, f-droid

I have an adb backup I created when the app was installed via Google Play. Now I want to uninstall this app and switch to the FDroid version of this app.

However restoring the "Google Play version" of the backup does not restore it to the FDroid version. What do I have to do to make the (original) Google Play adb backup work with the same app downloaded via FDroid?

Comment: Are the qualified package names identical?  Are you rooted?

Comment: @Matthew Read 1) I have no idea. The app is [FreeOTP](https://fedorahosted.org/freeotp/prefs). 2) Yes.